# Multistep selectbox in HTML and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, drop-down-menu

I want to create a html form with 2 nested select box,

And I want to do like that ,

1 selectbox , and user can select 
Modern Or Ancient . I did it ;

If User Select ancient , new options are :

```
Age : (textfield)
Determined By: (text field)
Age By c-14 testing
```

And,

```
If C14 testing is performed
Name of the body performing the test
Date of testing
```

Here's my HTML so far:

```
<select name="storedinage" id="storedinage" onchange="showfield7(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
<option>Please Select</option>  
<option value="Modern" >Modern</option>
<option value="Ancient" >Ancient </option>
```

and my JavaScript is here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function showfield7(name){
  if(name=='Ancient')document.getElementById('div7').innerHTML='Other: <input type="text" name="storedinage" />';
  else document.getElementById('div7').innerHTML='';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please remove that comment and add it to your question if it's necessary

Comment: Where is the javacript code? please add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [**jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bUBh/)

I think this is what you wanted. Let me know if otherwise.

I am not sure how your html looks like so I made a bit of my own, please copy what is useful. Don't know either if you want labels on inputs or placeholders, you will have to do those small adjustments.

**html**

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <select name="storedinage" id="storedinage" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <option>Please Select</option>
        <option value="Modern">Modern</option>
        <option value="Ancient">Ancient</option>
    </select>
    <div id="div7" style="display:none;">
        Age:<input type="text" name="storedinage" />
        Determined By:<input type="text" name="DeterminedBy" />
        Age By c-14 testing?<input type="checkbox" onchange="C14(this)" name="AgeByc-14testing" />
    </div>
    <div id="C14" style="display:none;">
        <input type="text" name="NameBody" placeholder="Name of the body performing the test" />
        <input type="text" name="TestingDate" placeholder="Date of testing" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**js**

```
function showfield(name) {
    console.log('!');
    if (name == 'Ancient') {
        console.log('passed');
        document.getElementById('div7').style.display = 'inline';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('div7').style.display = 'none';
    }
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('C14');
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        console.log('true')
    }
}

function C14(e) {
    if (e.checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('C14').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio , your code is useful . I needed them:) have a great day

Comment: @ArdaArslan, glad I could help! If it was useful please click to accept the answer.